# Multiple Foreach loop through a parents child

Tags: c#, foreach, parent-child

What is the best way to handle this scenario

```
        foreach (var level1 in Levels.Where(l => l.PARENTID == 0))
        {
            // Print "LEVEL 1: Title"

            foreach (var level2 in Levels.Where(l => l.PARENTID == level1.ROOTID))
            {
                // Print "Level 2: Sub Title"

                foreach (var level3 in Levels.Where(l => l.PARENTID == level2.ROOTID))
                {
                    // Print "Level 3: Header"

                    ... etc ...
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is fine. By 'the best way', do you mean 'the LINQ way'?

Comment: Give each `level` a collection of `Level` and recursively loop through. You end up building a hierarchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this using recursion

```
void ProcessLevels(IEnumerable<Level> levels, int parentID, int levelNum)
{
    foreach (var subLevel in levels.Where(l => l.PARENTID == parentID))
    {
        //print Level levelNum
        //use logic to format according to the specific level if desired
        ProcessLevels(levels, subLevel.ROOTID, levelNum + 1);
    }
}
```

You can just call it then using

```
ProcessLevels(levels, 0, 1);
```

This has the advantage that if you ever have levels deeper than just 3-deep, it will continue to process down the chain. You could also limit it at 3 levels (or whatever you chose) by doing something like:

```
void ProcessLevels(IEnumerable<Level> levels, int parentID, int levelNum, int levelsDeep)
{
    foreach (var subLevel in levels.Where(l => l.PARENTID == parentID))
    {
        //print Level levelNum
        //use logic to format according to the specific level if desired
        if (levelsLeft > 0)
        {
            ProcessLevels(levels, subLevel.ROOTID, levelNum + 1, levelsDeep - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And make your call like:

```
ProcessLevels(levels, 0, 1, 3);
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to pass in `LevelNum`. With the logic you put in, you could just print `ParentID + 1` and remove the parameter.

Comment: `LevelsClass` should be something like `IEnumerable<Level>`

Comment: @NickStrupat good point, I was just hesitant to guess at class names not in the OP

Comment: @TyCobb I'm not seeing how you could know how deep you were in the tree without some parameter... `parentID` I don't think is a level counter, it's more like a database ID and each item at level 2 would have a different ID and their children would reference to that